# two predicates in a sentence "... was deposited .... created..."

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

> The scientists reasoned that the clay was deposited from a world-encircling layer of dust enriched in iridium **created** a result of the impact of a big piece of space debris. (From TOEFL)

I think the objective clause possesses two predicates " was deposited" and " created." Is it a correct sentence?

Comment: The cited text is flawed. There should be a comma before ***created***, and the word ***as*** after it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the grammar of a "mistranscribed" sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica  ....Please note that I copied and pasted it directly from the test, "mistranscribed"?

Comment: I don't know the status of your source - when I search for unique fragments of your cited text, it only appears in two Chinese webpages that I can't access fully anyway. Whatever - I'm somewhat suspicious of the *phrasing* anyway (my bet is it wasn't written by a native Anglophone). But however that word ***as*** came to be missing, the fact of the matter is the text is completely invalid without it. And it doesn't matter ***who*** made the mistake - there's still no point in keeping the question open just so we can wonder how that mistake came to be made in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to consider the corrected sentence:

> The scientists reasoned that the clay was deposited from a
> world-encircling layer of dust enriched in iridium, created as a
> result of the impact of a big piece of space debris.

This is a complex sentence. The main verb is "reasoned"  and the object of that verb is "the clay was deposited from a world-encircling layer of dust enriched in iridium, created as a  result of the impact of a big piece of space debris."

In that phrase the verb "deposited" has as its object "a world-encircling layer of dust enriched in iridium" which is further modified by "created as a  result of the impact of a big piece of space debris" which tell how the layer of dust came to exist.

In this "reasoned that" followed by the rest of the sentence is the main predicate of the sentence. "deposited from a  world-encircling layer of dust enriched in iridium" is the predicate of the noun phrase that is the object of reasoned, and "created as a  result of the impact of a big piece of space debris" is the predicate of the modifying clause of the object.

The corrected sentence is grammatical, but it could be rewritten more simply as:

> The scientists reasoned that the clay was deposited from a
> world-encircling layer of dust enriched in iridium. This
> layer was created as a  result of the impact of a big
> piece of space debris.